# Testing a function in an angular factory with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I want to test a function inside an angular factory.

```
app.factory('customerSearchService', function ($http, $q) {

    var customerSearchByName = function (searchTokens) {
        //Some stuff
    };

    function createSearchStringFromArray(searchArray) {
        //Do some stuff
        return 'Processed string';
    }

    return {
        customerSearchByName: customerSearchByName
    };
});
```

I have tried to access the inner function, which results in an undefined message for the function:

```
describe("Services: customerSearchService", function () {
  beforeEach(module('AddressService'));

   var customerSearchService;

   beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
       customerSearchService = $injector.get('customerSearchService');
   }));

   it("createSearchStringFromArray is a function", function () {
       expect(customerSearchService.createSearchStringFromArray).toBeFunction();
   });
});
```

I could add createSearchStringFromArray to the factory functions, but I want it to stay private.

How can I access the inner function with jasmine?

Comment: This post might be helpful: http://philipwalton.com/articles/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link from runTarm 
(http://philipwalton.com/articles/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-javascript/) 
I have created a new service method for testing, which is removed by grunt for deployment.

Angular factory:

```
function createSearchStringFromArray(searchTokensArray) {
    //Do some stuff
    return 'Processed string';
}

return {
    customerSearchByName: customerSearchByName,
    /* test-code */
    createSearchStringFromArray: createSearchStringFromArray
    /* end-test-code */
};
```

Thanks runTarm!